# Differentiating output of layer with respect to its input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, weights, perceptron

Say we have a relationship $ z = Wx$ for a multi layer perceptron where $z$ and $x$ are $n$ dimensional vectors. When we find $\frac{dz}{dx}$ , I would assume this would just be $W$, not $W^T$.

I was wondering where this result comes from - I can't figure out why this makes sense.

Comment: It's a convention. You can use either convention (numerator convention or denominator convention) as long as you're consistent.